# Ring of Polynomials is a Principal Ideal Ring implies Coefficient Ring is a Field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

I read [this proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Polynomial_Forms_is_PID_Implies_Coefficient_Ring_is_Field) that if $D$ is an integral domain and $D[X]$ is a principal ideal domain, then $D$ is a field.

My question is if the requirements can be relaxed a bit, namely:

> Is it true that if $D$ is a commutative unitary ring and $D[x]$ is a principal ideal **ring** (this allows zero-divisors), then $D$ is a field?

I would be very pleased if anyone could give me a counter-example or could sketch a proof, certainly the linked proof would completely break down in this case as one could not use the properties of degree.

Comment: Interesting question! Clearly, if $A$ is a (commutative unitary) noetherian ring such that every ideal of $A[x]$ is principal, then $A$ is artinian.

Comment: For the record (for those who come here and may have difficulty extracting this from the given answer), the answer to the question is **no**, "$D[X]$ a principal ring" is equivalent to "$D$ is a **finite product of fields**", which of course is not a field if there are at least two factors (or none at all). See also [my question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/361258/18880) which is marked as duplicate of this one, but has more answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

More generally here is a semigroup version (from my old [sci.math post](http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/2950ee7d70900be3)). Please feel quite welcome to edit it (I don't have time now to TeX it).

THEOREM  $\ \ $ TFAE for a semigroup ring R[S], with unitary ring R, and nonzero torsion-free cancellative monoid S.

1) $\ $  R[S] is a PIR (Principal Ideal Ring)
2) $\ $ R[S] is a general ZPI-ring  (i.e. a Dedekind *ring*, see below)
3) $\ $ R[S] is a multiplication ring  (i.e.  $\rm\ I \supset\ J \Rightarrow\ I\ |\ J\ $  for ideals $\rm\:I,J\:$)
4) $\ $ R is a finite direct sum of fields, and S is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb N$

A  general ZPI-ring  is a ring theoretic analog of a Dedekind domain 
i.e. a ring where every ideal is a finite product of prime ideals. 
A unitary ring R is a general ZPI-ring $\iff$ R is a finite direct sum 
of Dedekind domains and special primary rings (aka SPIR = special PIR) 
i.e. local PIRs with nilpotent max ideals. ZPI comes from the German 
phrase "Zerlegung in Primideale" = factorization in prime ideals. 
The classical results on Dedekind domains were extended to rings 
with zero divisors by S. Mori circa 1940, then later by K. Asano 
and, more recently, by R. Gilmer. See Gilmer's book "Commutative 
Semigroup Rings" sections 18 (and section 13 for the domain case).

See also the following MR's (not meant to be exhaustive).

---

49#5213  20M25 (13F05)
Gilmer, Robert; Parker, Tom.  Semigroup rings as Prufer rings.
Duke Math. J. 41 (1974), 219--230.

---

Let  RS  be the semigroup ring of a torsion-free cancellative abelian 
semigroup  S  with zero over a commutative ring  R  with identity. The 
semigroup operation on  S  is written as addition. Such rings  RS  may be 
essentially thought of as generalizations of polynomial rings. The authors 
seek conditions on  R  and  S  under which the semigroup ring  RS  will have 
a given ring-theoretic property. Some necessary and sufficient conditions are 
found for the ring  RS  to fall into one of four classes of rings: Prufer 
rings, Bezout rings, almost Dedekind rings, and general ZPI-rings. The 
investigations are closely related to (but independent of) another paper of 
the authors [Michigan Math. J. 21 (1974), 65--86; MR 49#7381]. 
In Sections 2 and 3, the case of Prufer rings is considered. A Prufer ring is 
a commutative ring  R  with identity such that each finitely generated regular 
ideal of  R  is invertible. In order to state the main result of these two 
sections, we need some more definitions: Let  Z, [Q]  be the additive group of 
integers [rationals], and let  Z_0, [Q_0]  be the additive semigroup of 
nonnegative integers [nonnegative rationals]. Semigroups of the form  G /\ Q_0, 
where  G  is a subgroup of  Q  containing  Z , are called Prufer sub-semigroups 
of Q_0. A commutative ring with identity in which each finitely generated ideal 
is principal is a Bezout ring. It is shown that if RS is a Prufer ring then R 
is (von Neumann) regular. Further, the authors prove the equivalence of the 
following three conditions: (1) RS is a Prufer ring; (2) RS is a Bezout ring; 
(3) R is a regular ring, and to within isomorphism S is either a Prufer 
subsemigroup of Q_0 or a subgroup of Q containing Z . 
In Section 4 the authors deal with almost Dedekind rings (AD-rings). 
Following M. D. Larsen [J. Reine Angew. Math. 245 (1970), 119--123; 
MR 42#7662], an AD-ring is a Prufer ring in which regular prime ideals are 
maximal and not idempotent. Some necessary and sufficient conditions for 
 RS  to be an AD-ring are found in this section (Theorems 4.1 and 4.2). 
In the final section (5), the notion of a general ZPI-ring is introduced. 
These are commutative rings with identity in which each ideal is a 
finite product of prime ideals. The following result (Theorem 5.1) is now 
established. The semigroup ring  RS  is a general ZPI-ring if and only if  R 
is a finite direct sum of fields and  S  is isomorphic to  Z_0  or to  Z . 
        Reviewed by Uno Kaljulaid

---

82d:13019  13F20 (13F05)
Hardy, Bonnie R.; Shores, Thomas S. Arithmetical semigroup rings.
Canad. J. Math. 32 (1980), no. 6, 1361--1371.

---

Throughout this paper, the ring  R  and the semigroup  S  are commutative with 
identity; moreover, it is assumed that  S  is cancellative. An arithmetical 
ring is a ring for which the ideals form a distributive lattice and a ZPI-ring 
is one in which every ideal is a product of prime ideals.

The authors determine necessary and sufficient conditions on  R  and  S  that 
the semigroup ring  R[S]  be arithmetical [respectively, semihereditary, a 
ZPI-ring, a PIR (principal ideal ring)]. The main result is Theorem 3.6: Let 
 R  and  S  be as above and  G  the group of quotients of  S . Let  \rho  be a 
congruence defined on  S  by  x\rho y  if and only if  x=y+f  for some 
 f in(S/\ tG) . Then  R[S]  is arithmetical if and only if one of the 
following holds: (1) the torsion subgroup  tG  of  G  is a proper subsemigroup 
of  S ,  R[tG]  is regular and the semigroup  S/\rho  of congruence classes of 
 \rho  is isomorphic to an additive subgroup of  Q  or the positive cone of 
such a group, (2)  R  is arithmetical and  S=G  is a torsion group such that 
if its  p -primary component  G_p !=  0  for some prime  p = Char}(R/M), 
where  M  is a *maximal* ideal of  R , then  G_p  is cyclic or 
quasicyclic and  R_M  is a field. Two other theorems, 4.1 and 4.2, 
provide characterizations of  R[S]  that are ZPI-rings and PIRs. 
This paper is closely related to the paper by R. Gilmer and T. Parker [Duke 
Math. J. 41 (1974), 219--230; MR 49#5213], particularly the following 
results (Corollary 3.1 and Corollary 5.1): If  R  and  S  are as above and 
moreover  S  is torsion-free, then (a)  R[S]  is a Bezout ring if and only 
if  R[S]  is a Prufer ring if and only if  R  is a (von Neumann) regular ring 
and  S  is isomorphic to an additive subgroup of  Q  or the positive cone of 
such a subgroup (the authors point out that each of the above statements is 
also equivalent to another statement " R[S]  is arithmetical"), and (b)  R[S] 
is a ZPI-ring if and only if  R[S]  is a PIR. Applying their theorems, the 
authors give examples to show that the above results of Gilmer and Parker are 
no longer true if the condition "S is torsion-free" is dropped.
        Reviewed by Chin-Pi Lu

---

40 #1380  13.50
Wood, Craig A.  On general  Z.P.I.-rings.
Pacific J. Math.  30  1969 837--846.

---

A general Z.P.I.-ring is a commutative ring  R  each ideal of which is a 
finite product of prime ideals. Consider the cases (A)  R  has an identity, 
(B)  R  has no identity, but has at least one proper prime ideal,  and 
(C)  R has neither identity nor proper prime ideal. In each case the author 
gives firstly a structure theorem for general Z.P.I.-rings and secondly 
criteria for  R  to be a general Z.P.I.-ring. The structure theorems, 
which have been given in a less clear form by S. Mori [J. Sci. Hiroshima 
Univ. Ser. A  10 (1940), 117--136; MR 2, 121], are as follows.  R  is a 
general Z.P.I.-ring if and only if  R  is a finite direct sum of 
Dedekind domains and special P.I.R.'s in case (A),  R = F (+) T  in case (B) 
and  R = T  in case (C), where  F  is a field and  T  is a ring without 
identity and without non-zero ideals other than powers of  T .
                           Reviewed by D. Kirby

---

13,313e  09.1X
Asano, Keizo. Uber kommutative Ringe, in denen jedes Ideal als Produkt von Primidealen 
darstellbar ist. (German)
J. Math. Soc. Japan  3, (1951). 82--90.

---

Let a commutative ring  R  with identity element be called a Dedekind ring if 
it is the direct sum of a finite number of Dedekind integral domains and of 
rings having a nilpotent, principal, maximal ideal. Various conditions on 
 R  are proved equivalent to its being Dedekind, among them the following: (1) 
Every ideal in  R  is a product of prime ideals; (2) the zero ideal is a 
product of prime ideals, and if a prime ideal  P  contains an ideal  A, then 
 P  is a factor of  A. In the presence of the ascending chain condition, the 
following are also equivalent: (3) For every maximal ideal  M , there is no 
ideal between  M  and  M^2 ; (4) the lattice of ideals is distributive. These 
results generalize known conditions for an integral domain to be Dedekind. 
[Rings satisfying (1) have been studied by S. Mori, J. Sci. Hirosima 
Univ. Ser. A.  10, 117--136 (1940); these Rev.  2, 121.]
        Reviewed by I. S. Cohen

---

2,121a  09.1X
Mori, Shinziro.  Allgemeine Z.P.I.-Ringe.
J. Sci. Hirosima Univ. Ser. A.  10 (1940). 117--136.

---

A commutative ring R is termed a general Z.P.I. ring if every ideal in R can be 
expressed as a product of a finite number of prime ideals. Thus rings without 
unit element for multiplication and rings with divisors of zero are included in 
the class of rings considered by the author. As a main result the author proves 
that a ring R is a Z.P.I. ring if and only if (1) every ideal of R has a finite 
basis, (2) for every pair of maximal prime ideals P, P' (that is, R/P, R/P' are 
fields != 0) there is no ideal Q with PP' < Q < P, (3) there is no ideal Q with 
R^2 < Q < R. (The three conditions are independent.) This theorem essentially 
depends on the fact that in a Z.P.I. ring  P P_1 = P if P < P_1 and if R/P is 
not a field.  To prove the latter assertion it is necessary to investigate 
the relationship between the ideal theory of R and R/P. Finally the author 
formulates two theorems which are equivalent to his main theorem. For details 
and the methods of proof see the original paper.
        Reviewed by O. F. G. Schilling

Zbl Google Translation of http://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/Zarchive?an=0024.00801 
K. Kubo (s. this. Zbl. 23,102) characterized those commutative rings, in which 
every ideal from the whole ring and different from the zero-ideal ideal can be 
represented uniquely as product of finitely many prime ideals. The uniqueness 
idea is so sharply calm? that look for the occurrence of redundant (simply 
omitable), from the total ring different prime ideal factors to be excluded is. 
On this condition one (with more easily addition of the results won by Kubo 
themselves) receives the main clause: A commutative ring with unique prime 
ideal decomposition is either an integral domain, to which the well-known 
Noether five axioms apply, or a "primary, detachable ring", i.e. a ring 
with unit element, which contains only one prime ideal at ideals \p and its 
powers, whereby for a sufficiently large exponent \p^n = (0) becomes. 
-- By a Z.P.I. ring the author understands a commutative ring, which needs 
to be neither zero-divisor free nor contain unit element, and in which each 
ideal can be represented as product of finitely many prime ideals; Uniqueness 
of the representation is not demanded in contrast to the work by K. Kubo. 
The idea of the Z.P.I. ring is thus as far calm? as at all possible. As main 
results are emphasized: All Z.P.I. rings are O-rings, thus rings with maximum 
condition (divisor chain set). -- An O-ring with unit element is then and a 
Z.P.I. ring only if with no maximum ring prime ideal \p between \p and \p^2 
a genuine intermediate ideal lies (the "Sono condition" characteristic of the 
Japanese direction of the abstract ideal theory). -- The Z.P.I. rings with 
unit element are nothing one but those already 1925 of W. Krull (S.-B. 
Heidelberg. Akad. Wiss. 1925, 5. Abhandl.) in their structure exactly 
described "multiplication rings with maximum condition". 
-- A Ring \R without unit element is then a Z.P.I. ring only if it possesses 
a direct decmomposition \R = \F + \m, whereby \F represents (possibly only 
from the nullelement existing) a field, while \m is an O-ring without unit 
element, which does not contain of (0) and \m different prime ideal, and in 
which between \m and \m^2 a genuine intermediate ideal does not lie.
        Krull (Bonn).

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question although its means are beyond my math-skills :)

Comment: @Listing Gilmer's book is accessible to those who have mastered a university algebra course. You might find it enlightening to investigate how these general results specialize to your cases of interest.