# Example of finitely generated Z[x]-module which is not a direct sum of cyclic modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Could you give an example of finitely generated Z[x]-module which is not a direct sum of cyclic modules?

I have no idea about the example, could you give me some ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The ideal $I=(2,X)$ of $\mathbb Z[X]$ is not a direct sum of (non-zero) cyclic $\mathbb Z[X]$-modules.

Let's suppose that $I=(2,X)$ is a direct sum of (non-zero) cyclic $\mathbb Z[X]$-modules. Then there exists a family $(N_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in A}$ of (non-zero) cyclic submodules of $I$ such that $I=\sum_{\alpha\in A}N_{\alpha}$, and $N_{\beta}\cap\sum_{\alpha\ne\beta}N_{\alpha}=0$ for all $\beta\in A$. In particular, $N_{\alpha}$ are principal ideals in $\mathbb Z[X]$. But $N_{\alpha}\cap N_{\beta}\ne 0$ for $\alpha\ne\beta$ (if $x_{\alpha}\in N_{\alpha}$ and $x_{\beta}\in N_{\beta}$, then $x_{\alpha}x_{\beta}\in N_{\alpha}\cap N_{\beta}$). This leads us to the conclusion that $|A|=1$, that is, $I$ is principal, [a contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/show-that-langle-2-x-rangle-is-not-a-principal-ideal-in-mathbb-z-x).

Comment: You gave an interesting answer. Thank you very much. And I am interested in how you guys came up an idea of the example (2,$X$)?

Comment: @Joseph This is a well known example of non-principal ideal and as you can see to write an ideal as a direct sum of cyclic modules reduces to the ideal is principal.

Comment: Excuse me, I am a little confused that, why we can get:here exists a family $(N_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in A}$ of (non-zero) cyclic submodules of $I$ such that $I=\sum_{\alpha\in A}N_{\alpha}$, and $N_{\beta}\cap\sum_{\alpha\ne\beta}N_{\alpha}=0$ for all $\beta\in A$?

Comment: @Joseph Isn't this the definition of (internal) direct sum?

Comment: Thank you, and I think I need to think more about it.

Comment: why this implies that $|A|=1$? @user26857

Comment: @Ricardo if $I$ was a sum of more than one $N_\alpha$, then $N_\beta \cup N_\alpha \neq 0$ for all $\alpha \neq \beta$  would contradict $N_\beta \cup \sum_{\alpha\neq\beta} N_\alpha = 0$. So $I$ can only be a direct sum of at most one $N_\alpha$, i.e. $|A| = 1$.

Comment: @Vadim Do you mean $\cap$ instead of $\cup$?

Comment: @user26857 of course, thanks for spotting:^)

Answer (score 6):

Consider the ideal $I=(2,X)$ in $\Bbb Z[X]$.

Concretely, it consists of polynomials with integer coefficients of the form $a_0+a_1X+\cdots$ with $a_0$ even.

It cannot be generated by a single element $P(x)$ because you can never get $2$ and $X$ both multiples of a single polynomial.

But it is also false that $I=(2)\oplus(X)$ because $(2)\cap(X)$ contains non-zero elements (i.e. $2X$). A similar argument works if you attempt in any other way to generate $I$ with more than one generator.

The situation can be replicated almost verbatim for any ring which admits non principal ideals.

Comment: One more question, do you mean the module is Z[x} itself(Z[x] over itself)?

Comment: No, any ring as module over itself is cyclic and generated by 1. I'm considering an *ideal*. Recall that the $R$-submodules of a ring $R$ are precisely the ideals of $R$.

Comment: But my question is about a module over Z[x], so what's the module?

Comment: The ideal $J$ is the module.

Comment: Sorry, what's J?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $I$.

Comment: This answer doesn't prove that $I$ is not a direct sum of cyclic modules. I find the remark "*A similar argument works if you attempt in any other way to generate $I$ with more than one generator.*" as being rather vague.

Comment: @user26857 : you mean that I have to do all the work?

Comment: I've meant exactly what I said.

Comment: @user26857, me too. And, by the way, a non-principal ideal  in a domain $R$ is never free as a $R$-module because the product of any choice of subset of generators is a non-zero element in the intersection of the modules they generate singularly. This is precisely the argument given in my answer.