# Proof verification: $\langle 2, x \rangle$ is a prime, not principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ideals

I want to prove that $\langle 2, x \rangle$ is a prime, but not principal, ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

**$\langle 2, x \rangle$ is prime:** Suppose $f(x) = f_n x^n + \ldots + f_1 x + f_0$ and $g(x) = g_m x^m + \ldots + g_1 x + g_0$ are polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with $f(x)g(x) \in \langle 2, x \rangle$. Then $f(x)g(x) = xp(x) + 2q(x)$ for $p(x), q(x)\in \langle 2, x \rangle$. The polynomial on the right side has an even constant term. Thus, $f(x)g(x)$ must have an even constant term implies at least one of $f_0$ or $g_0$ must be even. Without loss of generality, assume $f_0$ is even, so $f_0 = 2k$. Then $f(x) = x(f_n x^{n - 1} + \ldots + f_1) + 2k \in \langle 2, x \rangle$. Hence, $\langle 2, x \rangle$ is prime.

**$\langle 2, x \rangle$ is not principal:** Suppose it is principal. Then $\langle 2, x \rangle = \langle \alpha \rangle$ for $\alpha\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$. So $\alpha \mid 2$ and $\alpha \mid x$. $\alpha \mid 2 \implies \alpha = 1$ or $2$. If $\alpha = 2$, then $\alpha$ can't divide $x$. So $\alpha = 1$. So $\langle 2, x \rangle = \langle 1 \rangle$ and $1 = 2p(x) + xq(x)$ where $p(x), q(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$. But this can't happen since the constant term on the right side is even. Hence, $\langle 2, x \rangle$ is not principal.

Does this look right?

Comment: this is related   [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/show-that-langle-2-x-rangle-is-not-a-principal-ideal-in-mathbb-z-x?rq=1) as to show it is not pricipal

Comment: On a purely cosmetic level, it didn't look quite right. $<2, x>$ is too "pointy" and $(2, x)$ is too "round". In my opinion, $\langle 2, x \rangle$ is the perfect middleground.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post.

Comment: The proof looks fine. For the primality of the ideal you can also see what is the quotient $ \frac{\mathbb{Z} [x]}{(2,x)} $ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ which is a field, so you can conclude that $(2,x)$ is maximal and so prime.