# Is the integer polynomial ring $\mathbb Z[X]$ an Euclidean domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Though seemed to be a common question, I couldn’t find any information on that.

I can’t imagine the Euclidean function would be like, if there exists one, so my guess is not. But how to prove it?

Comment: If it were, it would be a PID.  But this is a famous example....

Comment: No, $\Bbb Z[X]$ is not a Euclidean domain as it is not PID, to prove the last assertion consider the ideal $\langle 2, X\rangle$ in $\Bbb Z[X]$.

Comment: By the dupes, Euclidean domains are PIDs, but $\Bbb Z[x]\,$ is not a PID (we have *many* posts on such topics that can be located by search).

Answer (score 2):

No. Since $\langle 2, x \rangle$ is not an ideal generated by one element, $\mathbb Z[x]$ is not even a PID, let alone an Euclidean ring.

Answer (score 2):

This ring has Krull dimension $2$ but Euclidean domains necessarily have Krull dimension no greater than $1$.

Comment: How do you show $\mathbb Z[x]$ has Krull dimension $1$?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, the claim is that it *doesn't*.

Comment: Ooops, my bad. I wanted to ask how one shows it has  Krull dimension 2.

Comment: One can for example show that for noetherian rings $R$, one has $\text{dim}(R[x]) = \text{dim}(R) + 1$. By induction one also gets the analogous result for more variables then. This reduces the problem to computing the Krull dimension of $\mathbb{Z}$, which is $1$, since it is a pid (and not a field).

Comment: But also it is entirely obvious that $\{0\}\subseteq (x)\subseteq (2)$ is a proper chain, making the dimension at least $2$.

Comment: Indeed. I just prefer to see the general statement behind it.

Comment: @TMO Wasn't directed at you. I was about to say what you said plus what I said, anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are already great. Let me nevertheless state the following fact, which is a nice exercise:

$R[x]$ is euclidean if and only if $R$ is a field.

One direction is usually proven in standard algebra courses/books. Namely, if $k$ is a field, then $k[x]$ is euclidean with the degree as euclidean function.

On the other hand (to give you a hint): We can show that if $R[x]$ is a pid (euclidean domains are pid's), then $R$ has to be a field. For this consider the ideal $(a,x)$ for some non-zero $a \in R$. Now we can find some $f \in R[x]$ with $(a,x) = (f)$. Using the notion of degree and evaluation morphisms, try to show that $a$ has an inverse in $R$.

Comment: Of course we already have *many* answers which cover this FAQ, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/show-that-langle-2-x-rangle-is-not-a-principal-ideal-in-mathbb-z-x).

Comment: Yes, should have checked that before. My bad.