# algebra and ideal in A[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be an integral domain and $a\in A$. When is $I=(a,x)$ a principal ideal of $A[x]$?
My solution:
If $I$ is a principal ideal then $I=(d(x))$ with $d(x) \in A[x]$. $d(x)$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $x$, so $d(x)$ is equal to $1$. So $1=a.f(x)+x.g(x)$ with $f,g \in A[x]$. From there, it follows that $a$ is non-zero and $a$ is invertible.
On the contrary, if $a$ is non-zero and $a$ is invertible, then $I$ is a principal ideal. I haven't been able to prove it this.
Is my solution correct?

Comment: "Greatest common divisor" doesn't really make sense in a ring like $A[x]$. If $A$ is very nice, e.g. a field or UFD, then perhaps more can be said. Also, in the case of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the ideal $(2x,x)$ equal to the principal ideal $(x)$, so certainly it doesn't need to be generated by $1$...

Comment: Also, you should be careful -- "primary ideal" and "principal ideal" mean different things. A principal ideal is one generated by a single element, whereas a primary ideal means something very different, unrelated to the number of generators.

Comment: oh, i see it's principal ideal

Comment: I think d(x) is gcd of (a,x) if A[x] is a principal ring, so my answer is wrong. Can you help me with this question?

Comment: See the linked dupe, e.g. [this Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/36239/242).